# Html.Action does not render actionmethods annotated with [HttpPost]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the follwing method on my controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UnplannedCourses(int studentId)
  {
     var model = CreateUnplannedCourseModel(studentId);
     return View("UnplannedCourses", model);
  }
```

and in my view I try:

```
  <div class="unplannedcourses">
  @Html.Action("UnplannedCourses", "Student", new { studentId = Model.StudentId })
  </div>
```

But that gives an error: A public action method 'UnplannedCourses' was not found on controller 'Digidos.MVCUI.Controllers.StudentController'.

If I leave the `[HttpPost]` out, then it works, but I use the action later again from javascript so I would like to have only POST available.

Any ides?

Comment: why don't you just set it to `GET` and invoke it through your JavaScript code with `GET` as well?

Comment: I do all my communication through POST, so I want to continue that practise.

Comment: John Html.Actionlink use nothing(get/post) to pass control and you decorated your action with [httppost].

Comment: @Kannas: I've never mentioned Html.ActionLink...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think my best bet is a new attribute based on the MVC sources:

```
public class ChildishAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
   private static readonly AcceptVerbsAttribute _innerAttribute = new AcceptVerbsAttribute(HttpVerbs.Post);
   public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
   {
      var isPost = _innerAttribute.IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, methodInfo);
      var isChildAction = controllerContext.IsChildAction;
      var isAjax = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();

      return isChildAction || (isAjax && isPost);
  }
}

[Childish]
public ActionResult UnplannedCourses(int studentId)
{
   var model = CreateUnplannedCourseModel(studentId);
   return View("UnplannedCourses", model);
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, it´s nice and clean!

Comment: Thanks, I had exactly the same problem with the built-in attributes.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`Html.Action` is a html helper method and invokes your controller action with Http `GET` not `POST`.</strike>

`Html.Action` is a html helper method and invokes your controller action which accepts `GET` requests.

**Edit:**

If your intention is to protect that page from viewing through your browser, implement `ChildActionOnly` attribute as follows:

```
  [ChildActionOnly]
  public ActionResult UnplannedCourses(int studentId)
  {
     var model = CreateUnplannedCourseModel(studentId);
     return View("UnplannedCourses", model);
  }
```

**Edit:**

If you would like to invoke your action through Http `POST` via JavaScript, have a look the at following post:

[Working With JQuery Ajax API on ASP.NET MVC 3.0](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views)

Comment: Actually the `Html.Action` helper is not using any HTTP request to invoke the action so talking about verbs such as GET and POST would be incorrect. Also he mentioned that he wants to invoke the action from jQuery so decorating it with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute would prevent this from happening.

Comment: [ChildActionOnly] does not work, as Darin stated, it prevents me from using Ajax. My best bet for now is two of the same methods with different names. One with [HttpPost] and one with [ChildActionOnly]. Hopefully someone has a better solution.

Comment: @JohnLandheer when you look at the source code of the Html Action helper, you will see that it invokes the child action with the current `HttpContext` as your page: `htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext`. You can write your own if you wish, it is not too hard but not trivial as well.