# .NET MVC Razor Post Action - Server Error in '/'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post

I'm trying to fix this "Server Error in '/' Application" in someone else's code.  I am assuming they were trying to do something clever and never got it working or something has changed to make it stop working.  However, I have no idea if it ever worked.

Let me show you the code and explain the behavior and hopefully somebody out here will be able to help me fix this issue.  Thank you in advance.

### Code

There is a Delete button on the form:

```
 <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", new { queryId = uq.Id })' class="button small" title="Click to delete this query">Delete</a>
```

That is supposed to execute the following controller method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? queryId)
    {
        var userId = CurrentUser.Id;
        UserQueryService uqs = new UserQueryService();
        uqs.Delete(userId, (int)queryId);
        return View("Index", new UserQueryService().GetByUserId(userId));
    }
```

But execution never gets into the method.  Instead I receive the following information.

[image: Error Details]

### Tried

So, I removed the queryId parameter from both the href link and the controller and just made it an action (not a Post). Here is my test code:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Delete")' class="button small" title="Click to delete this query">Delete</a>
```

**Execution got into the controller.**

```
    //test method
    public ActionResult Delete()
    {
        var userId = CurrentUser.Id;
        UserQueryService uqs = new UserQueryService();
        return View("Index", new UserQueryService().GetByUserId(userId));
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the parameter passing code that makes it not find the controller method?

Comment: Check out this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756120/html-action-does-not-render-actionmethods-annotated-with-httppost)

Comment: your action is of type post, while you are doing get request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do HttpPost unless this is under a Form.

Reading your code it seems the delete button is not inside a Form that's why it throws a 404 error.

Replace your ActionVerb from HttpPost to HttpGet:

```
[HttpGet] //Change this from HttpPost to HttpGet.
public ActionResult Delete(int? queryId)
{
    var userId = CurrentUser.Id;
    UserQueryService uqs = new UserQueryService();
    uqs.Delete(userId, (int)queryId);
    return View("Index", new UserQueryService().GetByUserId(userId));
}
```

Comment: A delete action is changing data. It should be a POST, not a GET